# TypeError: Undefined is not an boject (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[**React Navigation**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FD5F.jpg)

I'm trying to learn about react native and I've got stuck at react navigation, when I tried to fix it, the problem is always about the `this.props.navigation.navigate`.

**Home Screen Code**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {TouchableOpacity,Button,Text} from 'react-native';

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ProfileScreen')}>
        <Text>Go to Jane's profile</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

**Navi Code**

```
import {TouchableOpacity,Button,Text} from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './ProfileScreen';

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  HomeScreen: {screen: HomeScreen},
  ProfileScreen: {screen: ProfileScreen},
});


export default MainNavigator;
```

**Profile Code**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {TouchableOpacity,Button,Text} from 'react-native';

export default class ProfileScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hallo </Text>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the `createAppContainer` https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html#docsNav?

Comment: yes i using the createAppContainer but still same

Comment: Can you post the code where you create the app container?